# Compiler Error in Xcode-4 Cocoa Application For GData Api?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, gdata

I am trying to Fetch Videos from YouTube Channel on Cocoa Application. For that First  added  GData Framework to my project, and import #import "GData/GData.h". Then their is no error . But if  i am importing #import "GData/GDataServiceGoogleYouTube.h"

and write some code  related to GDataServiceGoogleYouTube

```
 GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service=[[GDataServiceGoogleYouTube alloc]init];
```

getting Compiler eror:

```
    Ld /Users/Rasheed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YouTube-ddawzlgkbmkdqsalghaobsospjth/Build/Products/Debug/YouTube.app/Contents/MacOS/YouTube normal x86_64
        cd /Users/Rasheed/Desktop/MULTIPLESOCKET/YouTube
        setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
        /Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot 
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -L/Users/Rasheed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YouTube-ddawzlgkbmkdqsalghaobsospjth/Build/Products/Debug
 -F/Users/Rasheed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YouTube-ddawzlgkbmkdqsalghaobsospjth/Build/Products/Debug -filelist 
/Users/Rasheed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YouTube-ddawzlgkbmkdqsalghaobsospjth

/Build/Intermediates/YouTube.build/Debug/YouTube.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/YouTube.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -ObjC
 -lxml2 -all_load -framework Cocoa -o /Users/Rasheed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YouTube-ddawzlgkbmkdqsalghaobsospjth/Build
/Products/Debug/YouTube.app/Contents/MacOS/YouTube

    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataServiceGoogleYouTube", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in YouTubeAppDelegate.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can i Fix This error?

Answer (score 1):

If you built a GData static library, make sure the library is listed in the “Link Binary With Libraries” section under the “Build Phases” tab for your target.

If you dragged all of the GData source files into your project, make sure they are all listed in the “Compile Sources” section under the “Build Phases” tab for your target.

You might find this blog post helpful: http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/

Comment: Under Target Dependencies only one item that is GDataFramework(Gdata)

Comment: So did you add it to the “Link Binary With Libraries” section?

Comment: Yes, i added GData.Framework and libGDataTouchstaticlib.a in "Link Binary With Libraries" section.

Comment: this is cocoa app, so i think no need to add libGDataTouchstaticlib.a

Comment: Presumably you don't need to link with *both* `GData.framework` and `libGDataTouchstaticlib.a`.  But you need to link with some library that contains the `GDataServiceGoogleYouTube` class.

Comment: Suppose i link GData.framework then can i delete GData.xcodeproj in my application

Comment: GDataServiceGoogleYouTube class is present in the GData.Framework